Whatsapp-web.js package failing when scanning the QR code
client = new Client({
            authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
                clientId: phoneNo,
                dataPath: sessionsPath,
            }),
            webVersionCache: {
                type: 'remote',
                remotePath:
                    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.3000.1014590669-alpha.html',
            },
            puppeteer: {
                headless: true, // or false if you want to see the browser
                args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], // other Chromium flags if needed
            },
            ...clientOpts,
        })

This is my code to initialize a client using whatsapp-web.js package

My issue is in the webVersionCache url I used the latest pushed here in the repo but it's not working any idea what is the issue here and how to solve it. Thanks

Lates commit link: https://github.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/commit/bd46ca03c765648e9ce0f788670a788953d63fd8
I tried this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wppconnect-team/wa-version/main/html/2.3000.1014590669-alpha.html and I was expecting the qr code to pass but I got error Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'default')

There is some sort of expiration date to those files ( in my situation is 2.2412.54.html file )
I am using WhatsApp web Js i uploaded the delete file in a personal repo and used it in my app
but I get an infinite update page
however, for anyone depending on those files for a WhatsApp web JS bot
there is a solution that worked for me
delete the current whatsapp-web.js you have from package.json
and delete the node_module
then install this
npm install github:pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js#webpack-exodus

this version is from the WhatsApp web JS creator himself but on a different branch i don't know if it is stable or if there are features not included but for my use case it works fine
and even without providing a webVersionCache for the bot client
 this.client = new Client({
     puppeteer: {
        headless: true,
     },
     authStrategy: new LocalAuth({
        clientId: this.id,
        dataPath: this.sessionPath,
     }),
  })

working on my bot server

Hey Guys, Where do you deploy your services (of whatsapp-js), I tried with reder.com and netlify, but nothing works out!

I used @Bader's answer and it worked.
In my case given that I had other things in the project, I had to

Update some dependencies in Package.json for the latest version available
For socket.io lib, make sure both server (nodejs) and client (cdn) are compatible/same

==

If the issue persist, I recommend cleaning the node_modules and delete package-lock.json and follow Bader's instructions and run npm install

